# Python list arithmetic

Tags: python, list

I have a list of integers for example: `[30,21,32,32,41,20,21,32,21,20]`
I have a variable of X, X has a value within the range of the list.
How can I find the sum of all the elements in the list to the number of X.
For example if x was 4 I would want: `30+21+32+32`

Comment: By "before" do you mean the position of `x` in the list?

Comment: Okay I have given a bad example I will rewrite it, sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to sum the x first elements:

```
>>> l = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
>>> x = 5
>>> result = sum(l[:x])
>>> result
15
```

My answer may be not efficient, but I it is very straightforward.

Comment: Thanks, this answer makes the most sense to me and it works :)

Comment: Nops, it is not. He wants to sum the first X elements, including X. Look to his last example. @Cyber

Comment: My mistake. The OP has changed their question twice now and keeps changing their desired output.

Comment: That's ok. But I hope that I was not downvoted because of that.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to go is to use the [takewhile](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.takewhile) function from itertools:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> sum(itertools.takewhile(lambda x: x<5, range(10)))
10
```

In your case:

```
>>> l = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
>>> x = 5
>>> sum(itertools.takewhile(lambda i: i < x, l))
10
```

if you want till the 5th element, maybe use enumerate and zip:

```
>>> sum(zip(*(itertools.takewhile(lambda i: i[0]<x-1, enumerate(l))))[1])
10
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're a beginner, you should learn that the common way to carry out a task is *to define a function*

A function needs a name and usually needs one or more arguments, in this example `sum_until` is the name and `l` and `n` are the arguments.

Following the definition, there is some code that does the task for generical values of `l` and `n`.  Eventually the function `return`s the result of the computation, here the statement `return sum`.

Note the commented `# return sum` at the end of the function definition. You should try to control what to do in exceptional cases, here what we want to do when `n` is not found into `l`. One option is to return the sum of all the numbers in `l`, another one is to return a value that is *impossible* for a summation, and the second one is exactly my choice.

```
def sum_until(l,n):
    "returns the sum of the numbers in l that occur before the appearance of n"
    sum = 0:
    for num in l:
        if num == n:
            return sum
        sum = sum + num
    # return sum
    return None
```

Now, we have to *use the function*. This is achieved *calling* the function, that is you call its name and tell it on which *actual values* you need to operate the sum:

```
print(sum_until([2,4,6,8,5,10,12], 5))
print(sum_until([2,4,6,8,5,10,12], 3))
```

#### Output

```
20
None
```